# What is the Best Approach for showing Loading with provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am using Provider as state management in my flutter app. I am able to show loading with my `isLoading` bool which I am manipulating in my Provider e.g. setting true or false. below is the code snippet.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBodyBackgroundColor,
      body: (context).watch<BookingsProvider>().isLoading
          ? Center(child: LoadingWidget())
          : Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text("Loading Completed"),
              ),
            ),
    );
```

My question is that is there a better way of doing it? It came to my knowledge that there is a state emitting method that is better than this bool method but I don't know what is that and how to implement that in Provider. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Define "better" - what do you feel is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: what if I am using 1 Provider for suppose 4 screens and all 4 have different scenarios where loading can happen or not..... in this approach I have to make multiple bools that can be misunderstanding and irritating. I am not blaming this approach I just wanna know if there is any better available?